Inclusion in Hardy-Smirnov spaces for the analytic continuation of a Cauchy-Type integral with a continuous boundary function
Let  $D$ be a bounded simply connected domain in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}=\{z=x+iy\}$ with a Jordan rectifiable boundary $C=\partial D$. Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two distinct points on $C$, and let $\Gamma$ be an analytic curve in $D$ connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$. The curve $\Gamma$ divides $D$ into two disjoint bounded simply connected domains $A$ and $B$, the former on the left of $\Gamma$ and the latter on the right, where the boundaries $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ both contain $\Gamma$.
Consider a complex valued function $g$ defined and continuous on the compact set $\Gamma\cup\{P_1,P_2\}$. Define the Cauchy-type integral $F_B: B \to \mathbb{C}$ by the formula:
$$
F_B(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{g(\zeta) \, d\zeta}{\zeta - z}, \quad z \in B.
$$
Suppose that $F_B \in \bigcap_{0<p<1} E^p(B)$, where $E^p(B)$ denotes the Hardy-Smirnov class of holomorphic functions on $B$. As a reminder, when $\Omega$ is any bounded simply connected domain in the complex plane, a function $F$ is a member of the Hardy-Smirnov class $E^p(\Omega)$, $p>0$ when the holomorphic function $f(z) = F(\varphi(z)) (\varphi'(z))^{1/p}$ belongs to the classical Hardy space $H^p(\mathbb{D})$ of the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. Here, $\varphi: \mathbb{D} \to \Omega$ is a conformal mapping from $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\Omega$, which always exists by Riemann's mapping theorem.
Let $A_0\subset A$ be a bounded simply connected (sub-)domain with Jordan boundary $\partial A_0$, such that $\Gamma\cup\{P_1,P_2\} \subset \partial A_0$ and $\partial A_0\setminus(\Gamma\cup\{P_1, P_2\}) \subset A$. Assume there exists a function $F \in \mathcal{O}(D)$ (i.e., $F$ is holomorphic on $D$) that coincides with $F_B$ in $B$. Therefore, $F_B$ is analytically continued in $A \cup \Gamma$.
My question is: Is it true that $F \in \bigcap_{0<p<1} E^p(A_0)$?
I speculate that this must be the case since analytic continuation must preserve the growth of the integral means presented in the definition of the Hardy space $H^p$. Though, I cannot prove it.
